# Count Doctrine's iterate() Collection Result

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Having a QueryBuilder Result

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT....");
```

Fetching them by the iterate() method

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html

```
$objects = $query->iterate();
```

I am now able to

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $object = $object[0];
    //do something..
    $object->getObjectId();
    ...
}
```

BUT...

```
//after the iterate() call, before to foreach
echo sizeof($objects); //or count($objects);
//always "1", even if i have 10000 foreach loops
```

**Why and how to fix?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$query->iterate()` will only give you an iterator that is not countable. Consider writing a second query that does the `COUNT(result)` for you, or use the [paginator](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)

Answer (score -1):

maybe it's help you [doctrine2-large-collections](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-large-collections.html)

Comment: I am not in the position to install any extensions and does not solve the problem, why my collection is iterable, but not countable.